# Migration of Virtual DC to another ESXI host

Tags: domain-controller, migration

I have DC on ESXi host. I want to migrate it to another ESXi host on same LAN.

What is the best option?
[I already have vCenter and VEEAM)

1. Turn Off DC, and do migration from ESXi-1 to ESXi-2 using VEEAM
   Backup & Replication?
2. Turn Off DC, and do migration from ESXi-1
   to ESXi-2 using vCenter ?
3. Don't Turn off DC, and do Live
   migration from ESXi-1 to ESXi-2 using any of above application?

Or any other better option to ENSURE 100% successful migration ?

Comment: Do you have shared-storage? What version of ESXi and vSphere are you using?

Comment: Not using any shared storage.
Esxi and Vcenter both are 5.x

Answer (score 4):

Use the native tools, assuming you have a vCenter. You could perform a live-migration or cold-migration (*change host and datastore*), depending on your license level. However, vCenter may not be happy if the DC is down. Do you only have *one* domain controller?

Comment: I have 2 DC, but strange issue is that if my Primary DC is not onlnie, then the secondary DC also donot resolve any host, either local or internet. also when main DC reboot, it takes around 20-35 minutes to response to dns queries.

Comment: @SyedJahanzaib sounds like you don't have server or client DNS settings configured properly. Also, there is no "Primary" or "Secondary" DC - they are multimaster peers.

Comment: on Primary DC, primary dns is point to 2nd DC, and  secondary dns to loopback client.
on 2nd DC, primary dns is pointed to primary DC, secondary dns to loopbackup of 2nd dc.